# How to set read preference from java driver in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to set read preference to my 3-member replica set. How to configure it using spring.data.mongodb.uri from java driver. I want to set "secondary preferred" read preference.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used Spring Data much, but you can set replica set location and read preferences using MongoDB's Connection String:

`mongodb://example1.com,example2.com,example3.com/?readPreference=secondary`

[This link](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/connection-string/) explains more about the MongoDB Connection String.